# Flutter App crashing on Android using Google Maps Flutter Plugin

Tags: flutter, google-maps

I'm trying to set up googles map plugin for flutter folloing the Readme docs in pub.dev of the package `google_maps_flutter 1.0.6` https://pub.dev/packages/google_maps_flutter .
However the app keep crashing on Android, works fine on iOS.

Here is the output from Console:

```
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
✓ Built build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-debug.apk.
Installing build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app.apk...
Debug service listening on ws://127.0.0.1:58755/ub1_3ODfGto=/ws
Syncing files to device sdk gphone x86 arm...
I/FirebaseApp(16117): Device unlocked: initializing all Firebase APIs for app db2
I/zzbz    (16117): Making Creator dynamically
I/DynamiteModule(16117): Considering local module com.google.android.gms.maps_dynamite:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.maps_dynamite:201817000
I/DynamiteModule(16117): Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.maps_dynamite, version >= 201817000
V/DynamiteModule(16117): Dynamite loader version >= 2, using loadModule2NoCrashUtils
W/Gralloc4(16117): allocator 3.x is not supported
W/sharp.seeeA(16117): Unsupported class loader
W/sharp.seeeA(16117): Unsupported class loader
I/Google Maps Android API(16117): Google Play services client version: 12451000
I/Google Maps Android API(16117): Google Play services package version: 201817022
E/AndroidRuntime(16117): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(16117): Process: net.visualsharp.cab_rider, PID: 16117
E/AndroidRuntime(16117): java.lang.AbstractMethodError: abstract method "void io.flutter.plugin.platform.PlatformView.onFlutterViewAttached(android.view.View)"
E/AndroidRuntime(16117):    at io.flutter.plugin.platform.VirtualDisplayController.onFlutterViewAttached(VirtualDisplayController.java:181)
E/AndroidRuntime(16117):    at io.flutter.plugin.platform.PlatformViewsController$1.createVirtualDisplayForPlatformView(PlatformViewsController.java:233)
E/AndroidRuntime(16117):    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.systemchannels.PlatformViewsChannel$1.create(PlatformViewsChannel.java:104)
E/AndroidRuntime(16117):    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.systemchannels.PlatformViewsChannel$1.onMethodCall(PlatformViewsChannel.java:59)
E/AndroidRuntime(16117):    at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:233)
E/AndroidRuntime(16117):    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.handleMessageFromDart(DartMessenger.java:85)
E/AndroidRuntime(16117):    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI.handlePlatformMessage(FlutterJNI.java:738)
E/AndroidRuntime(16117):    at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(16117):    at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:335)
E/AndroidRuntime(16117):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:183)
E/AndroidRuntime(16117):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
E/AndroidRuntime(16117):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(16117):    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
E/AndroidRuntime(16117):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
I/Process (16117): Sending signal. PID: 16117 SIG: 9
Lost connection to device.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bumping the `minSdkVersion` from `16` to `24` in .../android/app/build.gradle fixes the issue.

Comment: it did not fix it for me

Answer (score 7):

Add `android.enableDexingArtifactTransform=false` to `gradle.properties`.

The issue and this solution on [GitHub](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/72185).

Comment: I an confirm that [this solution](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/72185#issuecomment-743971670) worked for me